# Is there any websocket ethereum provider?

Tags: external-api, websocket, explorer-api

Is there any websocket ethereum provider? Except etherscan one. Maybe there are paid wss subscriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Infura.io to connect to different blockchains. You will need an account and project id.

**Steps to create an Infura.io Project and remarks**

1) Open Infura.io page and sign up for an account. On your dashboard, you now can create a new project.

[image]

2) Change the endpoint to Kovan and directly copy the endpoint URL for connecting to blockchain.

3) The web socket URL is slightly different from the http interface — the correct pattern for web services is:

```
wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/{your-infura-project-id}
```

*Please, be aware that your personal API key to use Infura should be secret. So, don’t give it away to anyone else.*

Comment: This appears to be a lightnode.

Answer (score 1):

[Infura!](https://infura.io/)

```
wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws
wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws
wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws
```

Comment: don't see any info about wss in their doc, am I reaching the wrong documentation? Or how do I access wss one?

Comment: Nothing special to access: `var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'wss://mainnet.infura.io/_ws');`. You can track some of the websocket talk on [their GitHub](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/29).

Comment: Is it somekind of reliable/stable working service? cuz i don't see any responses from wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws

Comment: Isn't there any ready to use wss, which isn't in beta/is fully supported?

Comment: Try `wss://mainnet.infura.io/_ws`, note the underscore.

Comment: tried it as well, same result

Comment: connection failed.

Answer (score 1):

[QuikNode.io](https://quiknode.io) offers dedicated ETH nodes with https:// and wss:// endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Infura websocket support is now documented [here](https://infura.io/docs/wss/introduction).

From the intro:

> Infura's websocket endpoint provides support for Pub/Sub API as well
>   as JSON-RPC filter support.

Answer (score 0):

[Amberdata.io!](https://amberdata.io)

```
wss://ws.web3api.io
```

See [docs](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference/connection)

Comment: Hi @foba if you need to disclose something, please do so.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers  You may have edited around 10 or more questions with this website. Thanks

Comment: this is really awesome. normally I use infura but sometimes infura doesn't response on websocket.

Comment: @kodmanyagha Yeah! Did you try it out? We have a nice tool as well to make listening for blockchain or market data simple: https://github.com/web3data/web3data-js

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws"))
```

Comment: "connection failed"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Fiews?

https://fiews.io/

I use them for my [Chainlink Node](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node) and they work great!

Answer (score 0):

the best one for me is [Fastlynode](https://fastlynode.com), they provide private node but for the moment they only provide private node for binance smart chain, you can use this discount code FASTLY20 to get 20% OFF